# Fazer com que a div de dentro meio que "sobreponha" a div pai

Tags: html, css, css3

Tenho essa seguinte estrutura:

```css
.containerNome{
 width: 97px;
 height: 23px;
 
 border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
 
 background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
 
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.container{
 width: 97px;
 height: 112px;
 
 border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
 
 background: rgb(255, 255, 153);
 
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
<div class="containerNome"></div>
</div>
```

Da pra perceber que o elemento que esta dentro esta realmente dentro, gostaria que ficasse com um efeito meio que sobreposto... tipo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi bem, sobrepor como assim? mostrando aquela borda amarela em volta da div azul?

Comment: Se olhar meu exemplo, você nota que a `div` de dentro esta realmente dentro, e ela ate extrapola a `div` pai do lado direito, eu gostaria que ela se encaixasse perfeitamente, respeitando as bordas, como se fossem dois elementos separados, mas com o mesmo `width`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se removeres a `width` de qualquer uma das classes `.container` ou `.containerNome` esse efeito indesejado de estrapolar a `div pai` irá desaparecer:

```css
.containerNome{
 height: 23px;
 border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
 background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
 
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.container{
 width: 97px;
 height: 112px;
 border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
 background: rgb(255, 255, 153);
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <div class="containerNome"></div>
</div>
```

Eis o porquê disto acontecer. Neste exemplo temos 2 divs, a `div pai` e a `div filho` cujo a `width` é igual para ambas as classes, que neste caso é de `width:97px;`

```
.containerNome{
    width: 97px;
}
.container{
    width: 97px;
}
```

Até aqui tudo bem, este efeito de estrapolar não irá ser visível como se pode ver <kbd>[aqui neste exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/19506mvv/)</kbd> . Mas quando adicionamos a borda, aí é que este efeito indesejado aparece.

```
.containerNome{
    width: 97px;
    border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
}
.container{
    width: 97px;
    border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
}
```

O que é que acontece - A div `.container` por ser uma `div filho` e estar dentro da `div pai` ela vai respeitar esta e vai começar a ser renderizada a partir de onde acaba a borda (esquerda) e onde começa a área principal da `div pai` (que é a área amarela). Então ao darmos uma `border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;` à `div filho` estamos a acrescentar mais 2 pixels de largura a ela, pois ao adicionar essa borda estamos a adicionar 2 pixeis na `border-left:1px;` e `border-right:1px;`. O que dará um **total de não** `97px` **mas sim de** `99px` de largura total desta `div`. Para compensar estes 2 pixeis adicionais, teriamos que removê-los da `width` que ficaria - `width:95px;`. <kbd>[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19506mvv/1/)</kbd>

```
.containerNome{
    width: 95px; /* Foram removidos 2px para compensar o aumento dos 2px adicionais da borda abaixo */
    border: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid; /* Isto adiciona uma borda de 1px do lado esquerdo, topo, direito, e em baixo */
}
```

Quanto maior a borda for, mais teremos que reduzir no valor da `width` para que esta tenha no total `97px` de largura (incluindo a borda):

```
border: 2px #000 solid; => width:93px; /* 93px + 4px = 97px */
border: 3px #000 solid; => width:91px; /* 91px + 6px = 97px */
border: 4px #000 solid; => width:89px; /* 89px + 8px = 97px */
/* E por aí em diante... */
```

Ao removermos a largura - `width` esta vai se tornar `auto` como ela é por padrão, então o que acontece:

- Ao removermos a `width:97px;` da class `.containerNome` esta class vai calcular a `width` da `div pai` e preencher por completo toda a `div pai` a `100%` (isto já incluído e calculado juntamente com bordas, paddings ou margens).
- Ao removermos a `width:97px;` da class `.container` esta vai tornar-se responsiva ajustando o seu valor `width` dependendo do tamanho do conteúdo dentro dela que neste caso é uma div com `width:97px;`

> Atenção que a `width` por padrão a `100%` não será a mesma coisa que
>   `width:100%;`. A `width` padrão `auto` vai excluir bordas, padding e
>   margins, enquanto a `width:100%;` irá forçar o conteúdo em si, que
>   significa que as bordas, paddings etc vão ficar fora da `div` tornando-a maior
>   do que a `div pai`.

Comment: Algo tao simples.... tem uma explicação de pelo menos o porque acontece isso se eu adicionar o `width` na `div` pai?

Comment: Uma informação: Com exceção do Opera Mini, os demais navegadores [já estão suportando `border-radius` sem *vendor prefix*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius).

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio atualizei a minha resposta, dê uma olhada. Esforcei-me para explicar da melhor maneira possível, espero que esteja fácil de entender xD

Comment: Pra montar as div's da minha aplicação estou utilizando uma ferramenta online, acho BEM mais fácil, essa aplicação que adiciona o vendor prefix rs... http://makewebsimple.net/cssdivbuilder

Comment: Obrigado pela informação @re22 . ainda não sabia disso =)